# Using GL_INT_2_10_10_10_REV in glVertexAttribPointer()

Tags: opengl, glsl, vertex-attributes

Can anybody tell me how exactly do we use GL_INT_2_10_10_10_REV as type parameter in glVertexAttribPointer() ?
I am trying to pass color values using this type. Also what is the significance of "REV" suffix in this type ? Does it require any special treatment in the shaders ?

My code is as follows :

```
GLuint red=1023,green=1023,blue=1023,alpha=3;

GLuint val = 0;
val = val | (alpha << 30);
val = val | (blue << 20);
val = val | (green << 10);
val = val | (red << 0);

GLuint test_data[]={val,val,val,val};

loadshaders();

glBindAttribLocation(ps,0,"tk_position");

glBindAttribLocation(ps,1,"color");

LinkShader();

glUseProgram(ps);

glEnableVertexAttribArray (0);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, vertices);

glEnableVertexAttribArray (1);

glVertexAttribPointer(1,GL_BGRA,GL_UNSIGNED_INT_2_10_10_10_REV,GL_TRUE,0,test_data);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
```

The shaders are :
Vertex Shader -

```
#version 150

in vec4 tk_position;
in vec4 color;

out vec4 v_color;

void main()
{
    v_color = color;
    gl_Position = tk_position; 
}
```

Fragment shader -

```
#version 150

in vec4 v_color;
out vec4 fragColor;

void main()
{
    fragColor =  v_color;
}
```

The program object is validated as well. No issues there. This code works fine on AMD card,but fails on NVidia. Failing means I get NULL Pointer access at glDrawArrays() call.

```
Access violation
    Exception Flag: 0x00000000
    Exception Addr: 0x055f32ce
```

Answer (score 16):

If you are passing colors, then more likely than not you want **UNSIGNED_**INT_2_10_10_10_REV. So I'll pretend that's what you asked for.

The entire field is packed into a single unsigned integer. OpenGL defines an unsigned integer to be exactly 32-bits in size, so you should use the `GLuint` typedef that OpenGL provides to get one.

However, this format is *packed*, so you can't just shove an array into it. It's a form of compression, so it's generally going to be used when you're serious about making your vertex attribute data small.

First, the only reason to use 10/10/10/2 for colors is if your original source colors have higher color-depth colors than, for example, the regular 8-bit-per-channel colors. After all, the RGB components will each have 10 bits; if your source colors only had 8 bits, you haven't actually gained any new information.

So let's say you have some floating-point color values, with floating-point precision. You have to normalize each component down to the [0, 1] range. Then you multiply each value by 2<sup>10</sup> - 1, thus expanding to the [0, 1023] range. Then you convert each component into integers.

The problem comes with packing it into the actual field. The "`REV`" in the name means that the order of components is revered. Normally in OpenGL, if you see a format like `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5`, then this means that each unsigned short is broken down into a pattern of 5 bits, followed by 6 bits, followed by 5 more. The left-most 5-bit field is the Red, the 6-bit field is Green, and the right-most 5-bit field is Blue.

The "`REV`" means to reverse this. So `2_10_10_10_REV` means that the two most significant bits go to the *alpha*. The next 10 bits go to Blue. Then Green. Then Red.

So you have to bundle your integers on the [0, 1023] range, and then shove them into the right place in the GLuint value. And you do that for every such component in the array.

```
GLuint val = 0;
val = val | (alpha << 30);
val = val | (blue << 20);
val = val | (green << 10);
val = val | (red << 0);
```

This code assumes that `alpha` only has 2 non-zero bits, and `blue`, `green`, and `red` each have only 10 non-zero bits.

Comment: It worked fine on AMD but somehow fails on NVidia. Thanks for your response.

Comment: What "worked fine"? How did it succeed and how did it fail? Augment your question with the code that "somehow fails".

Answer (score 4):

So let's break this down into understandable parts:

`INT` means that the format will be read as an integer.

`2_10_10_10` means that the division of bits between is 2 bits for the first int and 10 bits for the next 3. Notice that these values add up to 32, the number of bits in a 4-byte integer.

`REV` means that the order of the components are reversed.

IIRC this format is most commonly used for packing vertex normals, in order to reduce the size of vertex data. Haven't really seen it used for anything else.

**EDIT**

Also, I found [this cool page](http://sugarpot.sakura.ne.jp/yuno/?OpenGL%E3%83%94%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BB%E3%83%AB%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9E%E3%83%83%E3%83%88) with tables that visualize exactly which bits represent which values. The site is mostly in Japanese, but the tables are in English.

**EDIT 2**

Link to the above page is dead, [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2033340&seqNum=3) is another page with a table of how the values are laid out.

Comment: That was useful thank you. Still the second part is unanswered. If I use this type for lets say specifying color values how do I code it? Following doesn't seem to work : GLint data[]= { 32767,32767,32767,32767 }; glVertexAttribPointer(1,GL_BGRA,GL_INT_2_10_10_10_REV,GL_TRUE,0,data); Also can you elaborate on what exactly is "vertex normal packing" ?

Comment: The table I posted show which bits correspond to which values in the shader. And according to the [man page for glVertexAttribPointer](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexAttribPointer.xml), you get a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` for setting the size to 1 instead of 4.

Comment: And vertex normal packing is when you take the normal vector for the vertex (normally a 3d vector, or 12 bytes) and compress it down to a single byte. You'll lose a bit of accuracy, but with normals, it's not a noticeable difference, but it reduces the size of each vertex significantly.

Comment: I am not setting the size to 1 here. GL_BGRA is the parameter I am passing for "size". 1 corresponds to "index" of the attribute.

Comment: Whoops, that's what I get for quickly glancing at your comment, I guess... The issue might be that `32767` isn't `0xFFFF`, it's `0x7FFF`. If you wanted all the bits to be set high, you should define your data array as `{-1, -1, -1, -1}`. At least that would be the reason you're not getting your expected result.